# C# Not able to return to my another class file

Tags: c#, return

I am trying to create an automation system but I am facing a problem here. Below is the brief description

```
main.cs

[Test]
public void Test_MyPage()
{
    LoginPageObject objLogin = new LoginPageObject();
    FunctionTest cc = objLogin.FunctionAbcTest();
    FunctionTest objAbcTest = new FunctionTest();
}

LoginPageObject.cs

// Login Functionality
//public void Login (some args){...}
// And
public FunctionTest FunctionAbcTest()
{
    //some functions to be called   .....(1)
    return new FunctionTest();
}

FunctionTest.cs
//Test automation functions are called
```

**Expected Result:** To return to FunctionTest class to continue further test

**Actual Result:** After some function which is called in (1) it automation gets completed but does not return to FunctionTest.cs

I really need help with this.

I would really appreciate your help.

**PLEASE NOTE:**

1. For more description, you can refer my project. 
   [Click Here](http://tbf.me/a/Bwi3Ap).
2. Please add full path to open excel file
3. Install MS Access Database engine 2010 (either 32bit or 64bit depending on your machine).
4. Install nunit 2.6.4 and run the project via nunit
5. Visual Studio 2013
6. Download will expires 1/3

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a homework solving website.

Comment: @Idos This is not a homework. Which way you see this as homework solving website? Please clarify.

Comment: You asked this [same identical question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34515402/1070452) an hour ago

Comment: Yes that is right. But there was some requirement which commenter needed so I thought to post a fresh one with updated details so that new viewer doesnot get confused with coments. Hope that is ok with you all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main.cs you need to add one line.

```
[Test]
public void Test_MyPage()
{
    LoginPageObject objLogin = new LoginPageObject();
    FunctionTest cc = objLogin.FunctionAbcTest();
    FunctionTest objAbcTest = new FunctionTest();
    objAbcTest.SpeedTest();
}
```

Also change your Xpath to

```
 [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//div[@id='cssmenu']/ul/li[3]/a/span")]
 public IWebElement UserForm { get; set;}
```

This will solve your problem.

And I think the site you have chosen is to use as an example to show why your function is not working. Probably, your original site id different. And it does not seems to be homework.

Please do let us know whether it worked or not.

Best of Luck in scripting your further code.

Comment: Yes, it did worked thanks. And also yes site I used in here is just an example.